# If there is a way to restore user input after failed server side validation using angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a page using angularjs, everything looks good except one thing: after user clicked submit button and the server side validation failed, the user input will be gone, but when I checked the html tags, the value="xxx" attribute saved the lost value, how can I get and render it to my page?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: this really depends. What Is used router or outer ui? In general this should be router ui with states, еруку have to be parent abstract state and form variable created there, and then you can work with it in child states.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your exact scenario, but what you can do is to make the copy of original model object and bind it to form

`$scope.editItem = angular.copy(originalItem);`

Bind `editItem` to the form.

If the server validation fails just call the above statement again and the editItem would be restored to original value.

Comment: Since the page has been changed, so we can not use copy here. Thanks.